# Right number output PHP

Tags: php

I want my number format like this:

```
1000 = 1k

10500 = 10.5k

1843 = 1.8k

17434 = 17.4k
```

But I have no clue how to do that. The language is PHP

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't expect people to do your homework for you here. What have you tried?

Comment: It is not that you have no clue, it is just that you have no will. Put some effort when asking questions to the community please.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$num = 14600;
if($num >= 1000)
{
    echo round(($num/1000),1) . 'k';
}
```

Comment: What will be the output when $num = 1000

Comment: edited. that should take care if it.

Answer (score 1):

This will fit your need.

```
<?php
$num = 10234;
echo round($num/1000*100)/100.'k';
?>
```

Comment: I think this will give a syntax error. Some thing like this " unexpected 'k' "

Comment: No, it won't. (Although the code is a bit ugly...)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number.

```
$num = 1000;
echo round($num / 1000) . "k";
```

Comment: unless you think a "k" is 1024...

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect if you add round() through it, so it looks like that: round(($num / 1000), 1) . 'k') - Thanks alot! Didn't thought so far at 4AM (my local time).